# CSS Child Margins do not Collapse while Angular Animation

Tags: html, css, angular, margin, angular-animations

I have two vertical stacked parent-boxes which each have several children. These children have a set margin-top and margin-bottom. In a static environment these child-margins collapse.

The second parent-box is hidden by default and can be toggled via a button. Applying an angular animation to the second parent-box gives a weird behaviour, where the margins of the children do not collapse properly during the time of the animation.

I build a working minimal example of the issue [here on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwe8fh)

What causes this behaviour? Can i fix it without changing the html and the margins of the children? (just removing margin-top for example is not applicable in my case)

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the children, remove their margin, the animate, and put back the margin (it's done implicitly)

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpensp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
export const ENTER_LEAVE_ANIMATION = trigger('enterLeaveAnimation', [
  transition(':enter', [
    query('.child', style({ marginTop: 0 }), { optional: true }),
    itemInvisibleStyle,
    animate('2000ms ease-out', itemVisibleStyle),
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    query('.child', style({ marginTop: 0 }), { optional: true }),
    itemVisibleStyle,
    animate('2000ms ease-in', itemInvisibleStyle),
  ]),
```